# Stroking a CGPath with a gradient?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I've been looking into this for a while now, and as a beginner, I can't seem to get it done. What I want to do is take a simple gradient, and use it to stroke a CGPath. I tried using CGContextSetStokePattern with a PNG the width of the line and one pixel tall containing my desired gradient, but this tiles the pattern, whilst I'd rather have it drawn along the path like a brush. Closest thing I can think of would be the Styler from Pokémon Ranger.

[image]

Essentially, I'd like my line to start out one color in the middle and move towards another at the edges. There's probably a simple way of doing this, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how.

Much thanks to anyone who can help me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in support for stroking a path in that way.

You could try to fake it by stroking the path multiple times, with each stroke having a narrow line width than the prior stroke and a different color, and maybe different shadow settings too.  Of course stroking it repeatedly will take longer than stroking it once.

Comment: Yeah, I know doing it multiple times does work. However, sometimes I have very long paths with many points which must be drawn and updated many times a second. I guess I could stroke multiple times, cache the image, and only redraw the new segments. I might do that.

Comment: Alright. Ended up going with your idea. It works well, and I got away with only stroking the path three times. If I cap the length of the line to ~150 points, it works fast enough that I shouldn't have to worry about performance for a while, going by the Time Profiler. I'll implement caching of some sort later on (which shouldn't be too hard) if it starts to lag. Thanks.