# Apple iOS BreadCrumb Example CGPath Route and Gradient

Tags: ios, mapkit, cgcontext, cgpath, linear-gradients

I'm using the "Apple iOS Breadcrumb" example to create a route with CGPath's, i know that each CGPath joined create my route, and, each CGPath use the CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor to fill the backgroundcolor but now, i want fill entire route with a Gradient Green to Yellow. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in support for drawing path with gradient. for detailed anser refer [a link] ([Stroking a CGPath with a gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979029/stroking-a-cgpath-with-a-gradient))

Comment: Oh thanks for the answer sir, so, could i use the CGContextSetStokePattern to insert an image into the CGPath's of my route?, i would like to insert "arrow.png" into each CGPath, how can i do that?

Comment: yes you can,                UIColor *arrowPattern = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
                CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, arrowPattern.CGColor);

Comment: But, UIColor colorWithPatternImage it will extract the color of the image and then, it will use it in CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, arrowPattern.CGColor), but that I want is insert the image "arrow.png" over (inside) each CGPath.

Comment: then you need to draw image and mask it with CGPath

Comment: I'm creating a BUS routes, but i want to use the "arrow.png" over the route to show direction of the BUS route in the road, like to say "for this road the BUS is starting the route, and for this comes" using the  arrow, is for that, i need insert that image over the CGPath....thank you very much